# ASP.NET MVC - Checkboxes as DropDownList elements?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to create a list of checkboxes as elements for a drop down list? I'm not sure how to accomplish this (or if it's even possible), as well as set the checkbox as checked if the value is true in the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are a couple of jquery based solutions you might find useful:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

http://lab.arc90.com/2007/11/28/jquery-multiselect/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with native browser widgets - you will have to create a custom solution that looks like a `<select>` element containing the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a commercial product. DevExpress has just such a control

http://mvc.devexpress.com/Editors/DropDownEdit

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see something that looks like a Drop Down List, but doesn't behave like one, it's a clever css solution.

Basically it's a hidden div:

```
<img src="image_that_looks_like_a_drop_down_list.jpg" onclick="showDiv('fakeDDL');" />
<div id="fakeDDL" style="display:none;">

     //lots of checkboxes

</div>
```